# maximal ideal in $\mathbb{R}$[x]

Tags: maximal-and-prime-ideals

Let $\mathbb{R}$[x] be the polynomial  ring over $\mathbb{R}$ in one variable .Let I$\subseteq$$\mathbb{R}$[x] be an ideal. Then

'I is a maximal ideal iff there exists a non constant polynomial f(x)$\in$I of degree $\le$ 2'

Is this statement is true?

I know that $\mathbb{R}$[x] is PID and hence an ideal is irreducible iff it is maximal ideal.

I know that degree of any  irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{R}$ is 1 or 2.

so according to me this statement is correct .

please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: What about the ideal generated by $x^2$?

Comment: What about the ideal $(1)$?

Comment: Non constant *irreducible* polynomial...

Comment: $x^2=x.x$ so $x^2 $ is reducible in $\mathbb{R}$ ok got it .this statement is not true other way that is $x^2 \in (x^2)$ but  $(x^2) $ is not maximal ideal. But

Comment: But , I is maximal ideal then   there exists a non constant polynomial f(x) $\in$I of degree $\le$2 is always true.